# Error al instalar Sass

Tags: nodejs, sass

Tengo un problema al tratar de instalar sass con node, por alguna razón cuando intento instalarlo desde la consola me da este error.

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\sass
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\sass'     
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\sass'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\sass'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\msnlo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-25T20_43_20_155Z-debug.log
```

Lo intente instalar desde la terminal de windows sin tener ningún editor de codigo abierto, o algo abierto en general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te indican los enunciados del error, puede deberse a que un programa lo está utilizando, como un editor de texto o incluso el antivirus. O por falta de permisos al usuario.
En windows abre la terminal en modo administrador, una opción es que en la barra de tareas en el buscador que tiene integrado escribas `cmd`, das click izquierdo sobre el símbolo de sistema y le das en `ejecuta como administrador` y luego trata de correr el comando de nuevo.

Comment: Abriendo la consola desde administrador me funciono, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmo que el ejecutar el comando como administrador, pero en ubuntu me sirvió:

```
sudo npm install -g sass
[sudo] contraseña para arnoll-tech: 

added 17 packages in 4s

2 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
npm notice 
npm notice New patch version of npm available! 9.1.1 -> 9.1.3
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.1.3
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@9.1.3 to update!
npm notice 
arnoll-tech@
```

Answer (score 0):

Si eso no te funciono puedes corregir el problema abriendo una terminal desde tu proyecto y escribiendo npm config set legacy-peer-deps true y lo ejecutas para luego escribir npm i react-facebook-login   e intenta instalar tus paquetes nuevamente.

Comment: El error no habla de conflictos de dependencias (que suele ser _ERESOLVE_), sino de una operación no permitida por el propio sistema operativo (_EPERM_).